# Pass the telerik grid column values to controller action result

Tags: model-view-controller, telerik, tags, actionresult

I have to pass the Id and Date value to action result(Update) in a Index controller. But I am not able to pass the parameters by using below code:

```
@(Html.Telerik().Grid(Model)
            .Name("NotesDetails")
                    .DataBinding(dataBinding => dataBinding.Ajax().Select("ListAjax", "NotesDetails"))
                .Columns(columns =>
                {

                    columns.Bound(o => o.Flag).Visible(false).Title("Flag");
                    columns.Bound(o => o.Id).Visible(false).Title("Id");
                    columns.Command(commands =>
                    {
                       commands.Custom("Flag value")
                                .Text("<img id='flag' width='20' height='10' src = '/Content/images/Flag.png'  >")
                               .Ajax(true)
                               .Action("Update", "Index", new { id=#-Id#, date = #-Date#  });
                    }).Title("Flag");

                    columns.Bound(o => o.Date).Visible(true).Title("Date");
                    columns.Bound(o => o.Author).Visible(true);
                    columns.Bound(o => o.Task).Visible(true);

                })
            .Pageable(pager =>
                {
                    pager.Style(GridPagerStyles.PageSizeDropDown | GridPagerStyles.NextPrevious);
                    pager.Position(GridPagerPosition.Both);
                    pager.PageSize(50, new int[] { 50, 100, 500 });

                })
```

If I give the values like  .Action("Update", "Index", new { id=123, date = "2000/2/2"}); I am getting result

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

We handle this in a Jquery way

```
command.Custom("Update").Click("jQueryFilename.functionName").Text("Refresh User")
```

and in jQuery:

```
jQueryFilename.functionName = function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
    var json = JSON.stringify(dataItem);
    $.ajax({
        url: Controllername/Index,
        type: 'POST',
        contentType: "application/json",
        data: json
    }).done(function () {
        var grid = $("#Grid").data("kendoGrid");
        grid.dataSource.read();
        grid.refresh();
    }
    );
}
```

You'll need to get set the jQuery selector to get your id and and date but that's pretty straight forward.
Happy coding!